# Adding Preloader: Integrating NProgress.js with ember.js with ember data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

i was trying to implement the NProgress.js a progress bar jquery library with ember.js when the ember is trying to laod data from the server. I could do it using Jquery Post in Ember successfully but, i don't know how to implement such using ember data when ember load data using Model.find().

User just have to add

> NProgress.start();

at the beginnig of the event and

> NProgress.done();

When the event is completed.

Here is my code that was used with Jquery Post method to Implement NProgress.js Progress bar in page.

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
reset: function(){
    this.setProperties({
        username: "",
        password: "",
        errorMessage: "",
        successMsg: ""
    });
},

login: function(){
    var self =this, data = this.getProperties('username', 'password');
    self.set('errorMessage', null);
    self.set('successMsg', null);
    Ember.$.post('login', data, function(){
        NProgress.start();
    }).then(function(response){
        NProgress.done();
        if(response.success){
            self.set('successMsg', "Successfully Logged In! :)");
            console.log(response.username);
            self.transitionToRoute('about');
        }else {
            self.set('errorMessage', response.message);
            console.log(response.message);
        }
    });

}
});
```

It works fine but i don't know how to use it using ember data, so for i did like below but the progress bar doesn't work correctly it just starts and ends regardless of data has been loaded or not.

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    NProgress.start();
    var data;
    if(data = App.Profile.find()){
        NProgress.done();
    }
    return data;
}
});

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params) {
    NProgress.start();
    var data;
    if(data = App.Profile.find(params.profiles_id)){
        NProgress.done();
    }
    return data;
}
});
```

I didn't know how to implement it so i did it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember data returns a promise, you can attach code to run after a promise using `then` like so:

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    NProgress.start();
    var data = App.Profile.find();
    data.then(function(){
      NProgress.done();
    });
    return data;
  }
});
```